# Views doesn't recognize a custom handler?

Tags: views

My Module contains (.module)

```
/**
* Implementation of hook_views_api
*/
function mymodule_views_api() {
  return array(
    'api' => 3,
    'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule') .'/views',
  );
}
```

and file mymodule.views.inc

```
function mymodule_views_data_alter(&$data) {
    dpm("viewsdata_alter");
    $data['entity_center']['field_center_verification_code']['field']['handler']="mymodule_handler_field_center_verification_code";
}
```

and handler class

```
class mymodule_handler_field_center_verification_code extends views_handler_field {


function render($values) {
    dpm("render");
    dpm($values);
    dpm($this->get_value($values));
    return "test";
 }
}
```

Comment: have you added the mymodule.views.inc as files[] in the mymodule.info file ?

Comment: added mymodule.views.inc but does not work
dpm("views handler") in the mymodule.views.inc has printed but the class mymodule_handler_field_center_verification_code is not recognized

Comment: the file with the handler class is also included in the files[] in .info ?

Comment: Yes, I have included both files in .info

Comment: in a folder structure views/handlers ?

Comment: @rémy I've been looking everywhere, but can't find the reason.  This only works for me if I include mymodule.views.inc as files[].  Otherwise it doesn't.  **WHY??**

Comment: there is no auto detection of module files, except .info .module and .install